# Java, generics does not work

Tags: java, generics

In my opinion it should work, but it does not. Why? Source code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.*;

class A
{
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> map()
    {
        return new HashMap<K,V>();
    }
}

class Person {}
class Dog {}

public class JavaApplication1
{

    static void f(Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>> peopleDogList) {}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        f(A.<Person, List<Dog>>map());
    }
}
```

Very simple code. Compiler error:
method f in class JavaApplication1 cannot be applied to give types;
required: `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>`
found: `Map<Person, List<Dog>>`
reason: actual arguments `Map<Person, List<Dog>>` cannot be converted to `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>` by method invocation conversion.

`Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>` is more general, so the compiler should be able to convert?

Also this: `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>> peopleDogList = A.<Person, List<Dog>>map();` does not work. `? extends Dog` means object that inherits `Dog` or `Dog`, so word `Dog` should be ok?

Comment: Is this issue the same reason why `List<ArrayList<String>> messages2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` compiles but `List<List<String>> messages3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` does not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Map<Person, List<Dog>>` is not compatible with `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>>`. In this case, the map's value type is expected to be `List<? extends Dog>`, not something that is convertible to same. But if you used `Map<Person, ? extends List<? extends Dog>>` for `f`'s parameter, it will work.

Here's a simple example involving more basic types:

```
Map<String, List<?>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();         // error
Map<String, ? extends List<?>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();  // ok
```

---

The OP asks why that behaviour occurs. The simple answer is that type parameters are invariant, not covariant. That is, given a type of `Map<String, List<?>>`, the map's value type must be *exactly* `List<?>`, not something similar to it. Why? Imagine if covariant types were allowed:

```
Map<String, List<A>> foo = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<?>> bar = foo;   // Disallowed, but let's suppose it's allowed
List<B> baz = new ArrayList<>();
baz.add(new B());
bar.put("baz", baz);
foo.get("baz").get(0);            // Oops, this is actually a B, not an A
```

Oops, the expectation for `foo.get("baz").get(0)` to be an `A` is violated.

Now, suppose we do it the correct way:

```
Map<String, List<A>> foo = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, ? extends List<?>> bar = foo;
List<B> baz = new ArrayList<>();
baz.add(new B());
bar.put("baz", baz);              // Disallowed
```

There, the compiler caught the attempt to put an incompatible list into `foo` (via the alias `bar`). This is why the `? extends` is required.

Comment: ArrayList<? extends Object> alist = new ArrayList<Object>(); - why this works? It is very similar. I don't see what is the problem.

Comment: They are similar, but not similar enough. For example, consider this: `List<List<Object>>` is not compatible with `List<List<?>>`, but it is compatible with `List<? extends List<?>>`. When you have a `List<List<?>>`, the element type of the outer list must be _exactly_ `List<?>`, nothing else.

Comment: Now I understand;). Can you also explain more briefly why if we have collection in collection this kind of problem appears?

Comment: @Pawel Sure, I've edited the post to put a good example of why.

Comment: +1 because of your first comment - it explains it better than the answer - you should add it!

Comment: `Map<String, ? extends List<?>> bar` - `? extends List` means something that extends List? Could give example of proper usage of it? Allowed operation of insertion?

Comment: @Pawel Right, so it means you could set `bar` to an instance of `Map<String, List<String>>`, `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, `Map<String, ArrayList<?>>`, etc., since `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, and `ArrayList<?>` are all assignable to (but not the same as) `List<?>`. Because these are all possibilities, and those types are _not_ compatible with each other, that effectively means that you cannot put any value into that map (except null).

Comment: @Pawel There's an acronym we use, called PECS ([producer `extends`, consumer `super`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/13)), that helps you remember when to use `? extends Foo` and when to use `? super Foo`. Basically, if you want to _read_ `Foo` values, use `? extends Foo` (covariant). If you want to _write_ `Foo` values, use `? super Foo` (contravariant). And if you want to both read and write, then you have to use `Foo` (invariant).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to pass a `HashMap<Person, List<Dog>>` to a method which is expecting a `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>>`.

The reason that the compiler won't let you do this is that the method you're calling might do something that's permitted on a `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>>`, but not permitted on a `HashMap<Person, List<Dog>>`.  For example, it might try to add an entry to the map, where the value is an `ArrayList<Rottweiler>`.  This is fine for a `Map<Person, List<? extends Dog>>` (assuming `Rottweiler` extends `Dog`) but not for any sort of `Map<Person, List<Dog>>`.

Comment: Ooh, you're a fellow Kiwi! Are you related to Brenda Wallace (br3nda/shiny)?